# How do I type a function object with additional functions attached as properties?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I'd like to create a module that exports a function that has additional functions added to it, like so:

```
export default function log(msg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
}

//Property 'warn' does not exist on type '(msg: string) => void'.
log.warn = function(msg: string) {
    console.warn(msg);
};
```

The usage of this could look like:

```
log('test');
log.warn('test');
```

How do I tell TypeScript that my function object has additional properties on it so that it doesn't throw `Property 'warn' does not exist on type '(msg: string) => void'.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would write it this way:

```
function log(msg: string) {

}
namespace log {
  export function warn(omen: string) { }
}

export default log;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
const log: { (msg: string): void; warn?: Function; } = function (msg: string) {
  console.log(msg);
}

log.warn = function (msg: string) { console.warn(msg); };

export default log;
```

In other words, a function type with properties can be declared as

```
type FuncWithProp = {
  (FUNC_PARAMS): FUNC_RETURN_TYPE;
  YOUR_PROP_HERE: SOME_TYPE;
};
```

If you want to type the attached function more closely to take strings and output them, and allow additional ones, then

```
type Logger = {
  (msg: string): void;
  warn?: Logger;
  error?: Logger;
};

const log: Logger = function...
log.warn = function...
export default log;
```

Comment: I really want that last example to work but I'm getting: `Type '(msg: string) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (msg: string): void; [level: string]: (msg: string) => void; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type '(msg: string) => void'.
const log: Logger
`